# ruby: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

After update, when I try to start my ruby app, I have an error:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Extracted source (around line #8):

```
8: <% account = Account.find_mak -%>

app/models/account.rb:68:in `find_mak'
app/views/layouts/_js_api_init.html.erb:8:in `block in _app_views_layouts__js_api_init_html_erb___274999121_65047152'
app/views/layouts/_js_api_init.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_layouts__js_api_init_html_erb___274999121_65047152'
app/views/layouts/logged_out.html.erb:17:in `_app_views_layouts_logged_out_html_erb__713588534_51277824'
app/controllers/leads_controller.rb:11:in `new'
config/initializers/newrelic_instrumentation.rb:30:in `call'
config/initializers/newrelic_instrumentation.rb:51:in `call'
```

but, I dont understand what was happened on line 8, how I can debuging this error?. If you need more information for answer, please write a comment. 
Thanks.

```
  class Account

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  attr_accessible :org_name, :time_zone

  field :org_name
  ... ...

  def self.find_mak
    where( org_name: 'Mak' ).first
  end
end
```

now error in other place

```
<%= form_tag "/apps/#{Account.find_mak.api_key}/users",
               method: :post, remote: true,
               'data-type' => 'json',
               id: 'register',
               :class => 'custom register' do %>
```

Comment: what's on `app/models/account.rb:68:in 'find_mak'`?

Comment: yout trying to run a method on sth. that wasnt excepted `nil` but is. Please post content of methode `find_mak`

Comment: the method "find_mak" is missing. please post the part where it says "def self.find_mak ...".

Comment: def self.find_mak
    where( org_name: 'Mak' ).first
  end

Comment: Update of what from what version to what version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bit in your view:

```
Account.find_mak.api_key
```

will result in the error you see if

```
 Account.find_mak
```

returns nil, which it will if no matching record exists in your database.

My suggestion would be to not use `#{Account.find_mak.api_key}` directly in the view, but assign it to a variable in the controller, which you can then check for nil:

```
def some_action
  @account = Account.find_mak
  if @account.nil?
    # handle this case, i.e. a redirect to 404
  end
end
```

Then in your view, you can use the variable and be certain it cannot be nil:

```
<%= form_tag "/apps/#{@accpunt.api_key}/users", #...
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your ideas and suggestion, also I want ask, our devs suggested use bundle exec rake db:reseed for solve this error, but it doesnt work too, I see rake aborted!
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass and list of gems

Comment: I'd suggest creating a separate question for that and including the seed file(s) and the error backtrace.